# findViewById in inflated menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, inflate

In the following code, findViewById returns null:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (view == this.getListView()) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        final Message clickedMessage = this.adapter.getItem(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(clickedMessage.getTitle());
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.showuser_context, menu);
        View button = this.findViewById(R.id.showuser_contextmenu_showthread);
        // I would like to call button.setOnClickListener here
}
```

And res/menu/showuser_context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/showuser_contextmenu_showthread" android:title="@string/showuser_contextmenu_showthread"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/showuser_contextmenu_reply" android:title="@string/showuser_contextmenu_reply"></item>
</menu>
```

I tryed to "clean" (Project -> Clean from eclipse main menu) the project, but it still does not work.

Regards,
ProgVal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get menu item by findViewById();
Instead you shoud use

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.showuser_contextmenu_showthread)
      //Your stuff
      return true;
   }
   return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
View button = menu.findViewById(R.id.showuser_contextmenu_showthread);
```

instead of :

```
View button = this.findViewById(R.id.showuser_contextmenu_showthread);
```

Comment: Good idea, but it still returns null. Same for `view` instead of `this`.

Comment: logically , it should works , because you have inflated  your xml in your menu , so when you try to find the views using this , it will search for your View on the ContentView of your Activity  ( not of your menu ) , that's why you should find your views in your menu  instance